# jquery make action when link menu item is clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have three menu items here:

JSFIDDLE: [FIDDLE LINK](http://jsfiddle.net/karimkhan/ZjgV4/2/)

```
<div class="home-content">
                <div class="menu-bar">
                        <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
                          <li class="active"><a href="#">Blue<sup>beta</sup></a></li>
                          <li><a href="#">Green<sup>beta</sup></a></li>
                          <li><a href="#">Red</a></li>
                        </ul>                        
                </div>
```

By default link `blue` is active.

1. I want whenever any link `green` or `red` is clicked, it should be active
2. Color of the label should be changed as per the link selected

I am facing trouble in this points.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could add a DATA color on your `li` like that :

```
<li data-color="#0f0"><a href="#">Green<sup>beta</sup></a></li>
```

then use this code :

```
$(function () {
    $(".menu-bar li a").click(function () {
        $('.active').removeClass('active'); //Remove the current active item
        var color = $(this).closest('li').addClass('active').data('color'); //add class the the target and save his data attribute
        $("#l1").css("color", color); //Change color
    });
});
```

Fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/ZjgV4/6/

Comment: thanks, small change. I have edited code here, I want to get id of link when it is clicked, can you please help - http://jsfiddle.net/karimkhan/Sv3Vm/2/

Comment: 2 ways. Faster but will not work if you wrap your `a` : `var id = this.parentNode.id;`. Will mostly always work : `var id = $(this).closest('li')[0].id;`.

Comment: Which one is better? suggested by you or mine? I am not sure

Comment: I don't understand how your work since `this` is the `a` and the id is on the `li` but im pretty sure the vanilla js is the faster. Also, `.prop` is better than `.attr();` Ill run some texts

Comment: @Programming_crazy Check what is faster here http://jsperf.com/id-selector-test-54

Answer (score 1):

Something like this?

```
  $(function () {
      $(".menu-bar li a").click(function () {
             $(".menu-bar li").removeClass("active");
             $(this).parent().addClass("active");
      });
  });
```

http://jsfiddle.net/3mhCW/1/

Answer (score 1):

Without completely doing everything, this should point you on the right track. A few things to note about your code - You should pass in the e event, to the click handler and use jQuery's `e.preventDefault();` to stop the link. Also, you need to quote the value in the css function. `.css("color", "red")` otherwise you will get an undefined error that red is not defined. Instead of manipulating the css of the elements, I would use add/removeClass respectively and style the elements with css.

```
$(function () {

                    $(".menu-bar li a").click(function (e) {
                        e.preventDefault(); // stop the link from following the href


                        // remove the active class from everything
                        $(".active").removeClass("active");

                        // $(this).css("color", "red"); 
                        $(this).addClass("active");

                    });
                });
```

Answer (score -1):

I included the code here.
basically, i inserted the color name to a class each color has its own class and each LI has a [global attribute data-*](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_global_data.asp) with the value of the color (the name of the class)

HTML:
    add to all the li the attribute `data-color="blue"`

Add CSS:

```
.blue{
    background-color:blue;
}
.green{
    background-color:green;
}
.red{
    background-color:red;
}
```

jQuery:

```
$(function () {
    $(".menu-bar li a").click(function () {
        $('.menu-bar li.active').removeClass('active');
        $(this).parent().addClass('active');
        $("#l1").attr('class',$('.menu-bar li.active').attr('data-color'));         
    });
});
```